# Javascript: How to check boolean value from code-behind in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a boolean property in code-behind ASP.NET, now I want to use it in Javascript of mark-up file, but Javascript do not understand True, or False. SO now, I'm using this:

```
if ( '<%=IsTabVisible%>' == 'True'){
///
}
```

It works, but quite ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: What does the generated code look like?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way I see it you have three options:

A. Do what you are already doing.

B. Perform the `if` test on the server-side, something like this:

> ```
> <% if (IsTabVisible) { %>
>     // client-side code here, whatever you had inside the brackets
>     // of your original if statement
> <% } %>
> ```

C. Make sure you generate 'true' and 'false' in lowercase so that it will work as client-side JavaScript, something like this:

`if (<%= IsTabVisible ? "true" : "false" %>)`

Which will appear to the client as:

```
if (true)
```

or

```
if (false)
```

Option A may look a bit funny but it works fine. Option C produces pretty client-side code that probably nobody will see. My preference is Option B.

Comment: Option C makes Visual Studio complain, a bunch of errors on the page like `Syntax error` and `Expected ')'`, I think because the Javascript thinks you have an empty `if()` statement.  Did this work at some point and is now broken or what?

Comment: @ToastyMallows - Option C uses valid C# which produces valid JavaScript. I haven't used Visual Studio since 2011, but back then it sometimes used to report JS "errors" or warnings for valid JS because it got confused if server-side code was mixed into the JS - but the code would still run.